# Strange behavior with reflection in Scala

Tags: scala, reflection, scala-2.10

I was trying to follow an example from another question, and I came upon something I cannot explain:

```
scala> import scala.reflect.runtime.{currentMirror => m}
import scala.reflect.runtime.{currentMirror=>m}

scala> m.mkToolBox()
<console>:12: error: value mkToolBox is not a member of reflect.runtime.universe.Mirror
              m.mkToolBox()
                ^

scala> import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox
import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox

scala> m.mkToolBox()
res3: scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox[reflect.runtime.universe.type] = scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxFactory$ToolBoxImpl@225765b0
```

How come `mkToolBox` is not a member of `m` before importing `ToolBox`, but is afterwards?

Answer (score 3):

`ToolBox` is an implicit class that pimps `mkToolBox` onto `Mirror`. Same story with `Eval`, which pimps `eval`.

Comment: An implicit class? That certainly explains the unconventionally named method.

Answer (score 2):

If I examine it with `reify`, I see this:

```
scala> reify{ m.mkToolBox() }.tree
res4: reflect.runtime.universe.Tree = 
{
  val qual$1 = scala.tools.reflect.`package`.ToolBox(scala.reflect.runtime.`package`.m);
  val x$1 = qual$1.mkToolBox$default$1;
  val x$2 = qual$1.mkToolBox$default$2;
  qual$1.mkToolBox(x$1, x$2)
}
```

That means there's a method call to a function named `ToolBox` inside the package object `scala.tools.reflect`. It is not an object, because `reify` would expose the `apply` method.

So, even though the [API Docs for the Compiler](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/compiler/index.html#scala.tools.reflect.package) do not show anything but the trait on the left side, if you look at the package you'll see an implicit method definition.

PS: Yes, this was a real question. The thought of an uppercase-starting method with the same name of a trait did not occur to me, until I thought of reifying the thing to get the tree.

Comment: What I do in such situations: I look to the sources to recognize what is going on there. ;)

Comment: @Antoras It has been a long while since some Scala code left me befuddled as to its meaning. The explanation is rather obvious, but thinking of `ToolBox` as a method really didn't occur to me.