# How to reload and call an external scala file's method from a Scala application

Tags: java, scala, compilation, runtime, external

I tried below code but that is a java code and works only for.java files.

```
   try {
        JavaCompiler jc = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
        StandardJavaFileManager sjfm = jc.getStandardFileManager(null, null, null);
        File javaFile = new File("/home/rishi/Desktop/Test.java");
        Iterable fileObjects = sjfm.getJavaFileObjects(javaFile);

        String[] options = new String[]{
                "-d", "/home/rishi/Desktop/bin"
        };

        jc.getTask(null, null, null, Arrays.asList(options), null, fileObjects).call();
        sjfm.close();
        System.out.println("Class has been successfully compiled");
        URL[] urls = new URL[]{new URL("file:///home/rishi/Desktop/")};
        URLClassLoader ucl = new URLClassLoader(urls);
        Class clazz = ucl.loadClass("PostProcessing");
        System.out.println("Class has been successfully loaded");

        Method method = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("call", null);

        Object object = clazz.newInstance();
        method.invoke(object, null);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I want Scala code for the same.

I also tried below code which takes .class file which can be generated by either Java or Scala.

```
 URL[] urls = new URL[]{new URL("file:///home/rishi/Desktop/")};
        URLClassLoader ucl = new URLClassLoader(urls);
        Class clazz = ucl.loadClass("PostProcessing");
        System.out.println("Class has been successfully loaded");

        Method method = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("call", null);

        Object object = clazz.newInstance();
        method.invoke(object, null);
```

Still, I faced issues with .class file generated by Scala. It is working for Java .class file.

PostProcessing.Scala :

```
class PostProcessing {
def call = println("Hurray !! You called me")
```

}

PostProcessing.java

```
public class PostProcessing {
public void call() {System.out.println("Hurray !! You called me");}
```

}

**Update :**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;
import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.tools.JavaCompiler;
import javax.tools.StandardJavaFileManager;
import javax.tools.ToolProvider;
```

Please suggest me the solution.

Comment: add import section to your examples.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23874281/scala-how-to-compile-code-from-an-external-file-at-runtime